# Magento1.9 - Cart page subtotal is wrong

Tags: magento-1.9, price, shopping-cart, subtotal

I am facing on the issue in My `Magento1.9` cart page where the product subtotal is different than expected.

**Expected result:**

```
Unit Price * QTY = Subtotal
```

**Actual result:**

```
Unite Price * QTY = Some other price
```

Please see the screenshot for more detail.

[image]

```
Magento 1.9.3.1

PHP 7.2.27
```

I have also tried https://github.com/hartmut-co-uk/magento-php7-totals-fix and https://magento.com/tech-resources/download#download2240

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the same issues as described here :

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-1-x-Version-Upgrades/Cart-displays-wrong-price-after-exceeding-stock-value-Version-1/m-p/72784

You can apply this as a fix :

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-1-x-Version-Upgrades/Cart-displays-wrong-price-after-exceeding-stock-value-Version-1/m-p/72784#M2453

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Ylgen Guxholli but this solution is not working for me :(